# Squeezing characters with python

Tags: python, regex

How would I do this with python :

if  I have a string formatted like :

```
A..a.b.c
```

To make it like :

```
A.a.b.c
```

But I do not know beforehand how many dots I have ?

It's like the tr -s function in linux

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You want to replace every run of **TWO or more dots** by a single dot. That is achieved like this:

```
>>> import re
>>> re.sub(r'\.\.+', '.', 'A..a.b.c')
'A.a.b.c'
```

You **don't want and don't need** to replace every run of **ONE or more dots** by a single dot.

```
>>> re.sub(r'\.+', '.', 'A..a.b.c')
'A.a.b.c'
```

That produces the same result but does pointless substitutions of lone dots (3 on your example) and is consequently much slower.

Timings:

```
python -mtimeit -s"import re;subber=re.compile(r'\.+').sub;s=1000*'a.'" "subber('.',s)"
1000 loops, best of 3: 212 usec per loop

python -mtimeit -s"import re;subber=re.compile(r'\.\.+').sub;s=1000*'a.'" "subber('.',s)"
10000 loops, best of 3: 23.2 usec per loop
```

Comment: You could also use `r'\.{2,}'`.

Comment: @icktoofay: Yes, you could. It's more general, but slower.

Comment: Is optimization really needed here?  Most people find regexes to be difficult to verify and maintain, so it is usually the case that the simplest-regex-that-works is the one you want to have in your code base.

Comment: @RaymondHettinger: Optimisation is never "really needed". I was pointing out that a regex that was written to match the requirement had the bonus effect that it was faster than one that didn't match the requirement. All of the regexes in answers to this question are of the kind that should be quite easy for most people to understand, verify, and maintain.

Answer (score 7):

If you want a general format to replace any sequence of repeated characters with just one of those characters:

```
>>> import re
>>> s='aaa,,bb,c'
>>> re.sub(r'(.)(\1+)', r'\1', s)
'a,b,c'
```

If you want to limit by only certain characters:

```
>>> re.sub(r'([\w])(\1+)', r'\1', s)
'a,,b,c'
>>> re.sub(r'([,])(\1+)', r'\1', s)
'aaa,bb,c'
```

And your example:

```
>>> s='A..a.b.c'
>>> re.sub(r'([.])(\1+)', r'\1', s)
'A.a.b.c'
```

Answer (score 5):

[Regular expression substitution](http://docs.python.org/library/re.html#re.sub) is good at finding patterns (repeated dots) and replacing them (with a single dot):

```
>>> import re
>>> re.sub(r'\.+', '.', 'A..a.b.c')
'A.a.b.c'
```

Comment: Additional info from Python regex HOWTO:
http://docs.python.org/howto/regex.html#search-and-replace

Answer (score 2):

If you don't really have to use regex's, here is a pure Python version, only works with dots:

```
>>> ".".join(filter(bool, "A..a.b.c".split(".")))
'A.a.b.c'
```

Comment: [-1] or perhaps `".".join(x for x in "A..a.b.c".split(".") if x)` ... however both **FAIL** on input that has leading or training runs of one or more dots. Examples: `'a.'` or `'.b'` or `'.'`