# Python remove separating spaces

Tags: python

You may or may not have heard of Willie, the Python IRC bot.

I have a trigger.group(2) object:

```
'J O I N   : # S t a f f'
```

How do I make this become:

```
'JOIN :#Staff'
```

Edit:
Basically I want to remove the spaces between the characters without removing the "real" spaces, between `N :`. Note that the command could be anything with any number of arguments: `PRIVMSG`, `OPER`, etc.

Comment: Can you be more specific about the transformation rule you want to apply to the first string?  Right now it's not clear.

Comment: This might be of interest: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7940619/squeezing-characters-with-python

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Since you have alternating spaces and non-spaces, try taking every second character:

```
s = s[::2]
```

Example:

```
>>> 'J O I N   : # S t a f f'[::2]
'JOIN :#Staff'
```

Comment: turns out the `willie.write(s)` method was doing a `' '.join(s)`. This solution would have fixed that but I opted to bypass that method entirely. Thanks!

Comment: I suspect it wanted a list of parts, e.g. `willie.write(['JOIN', ':#Staff'])`. Regardless, I'm glad you fixed your issue!

Answer (score 1):

```
>>> import re
>>> text = 'J O I N   : # S t a f f'
>>> re.sub(r'(?<=\S)\s|\s(?=\S)', '', text)
'JOIN :#Staff'
```

Answer (score 0):

```
def rmspace_separate(string, spacelimiter=' '*2):
    return ' '.join(s.replace(' ', '') for s in s.split(spacelimiter))
```

would work. change `spacelimiter` to suit your needs.

Comment: @nneonneo yeah changed it.